# Categorical bubble plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, bubble-chart

I have a dataset with a lot of categorical variables and a binary target variable. What package is available in Python or other opensource GUI-based software where I can scatterplot two categorical variables on the X and Y axis and use the target variable as hue?

I have looked at Seaborn's catplot, but for that, one axis has to be numerical while the other categorical. So it doesn't serve this case.

For example, you can use the following:

```
import seaborn as sns
data = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
```

Here are the plot features I want

X-axis - 'embark_town'
Y-axis - 'class'
hue - 'alive'

Comment: You can do it with pyplot. Provide a sample of your data and your expected output.

Comment: pakpe - I have added data to the post. please reply.

Comment: @Mr. T - Seaborn is pretty but non-seaborn is also ok. Alive has values 'yes' and 'no'. I had frequencies of X and Y variables shown as bubbles for yes and no in my mind..Not sure if that is even doable in any of python packages. I tried to search on google, but could not find any.

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn supports, just like matplotlib, the plotting of categorical vs categorical variables. One can create semitransparent markers that allow to see both categories, although this might be difficult to distinguish from one marker if both are of similar size. The essential plot is rather easy - we transform the dataframe with groupby and size to count the entries per triplet embarking town - class - alive category, then create a scatterplot with count value as markersize. However, the legend entry is the complicated part here. Either the markersize is tiny in the plot or massive in the legend. I tried to balance this but I am not happy with the result. A lot of manual adjusting necessary here, so seaborn is no real advantage here. Any suggestions on how to simplify this within seaborn are welcome.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#dataframe and categories 
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
X = "embark_town"
Y = "class"
H = "alive"

#counting the X-Y-H category entries
plt_df = df.groupby([X, Y, H]).size().to_frame(name="people").reset_index()

#figure preparation with grid and scaling
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
ax.set_ylim(plt_df[Y].unique().size-0.5, -0.5)
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, plt_df[X].unique().size+1.0)
ax.grid(ls="--")

#the actual scatterplot with markersize representing the counted values
sns.scatterplot(x=X,
                y=Y,
                size="people",
                sizes=(100, 10000),
                alpha=0.5,
                edgecolor="black",
                hue=H,
                data=plt_df,
                ax=ax)

#creating two legends because the hue markers differ in size from the others
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
l = ax.legend(handles[:3], labels[:3], title="The poor die first", markerscale=2, loc="upper right")
ax.add_artist(l)
#and seaborn plots the size markers in black, so you would get massive black blobs in the legend
#we change the color and make them transparent
for handle in handles:
    handle.set_facecolors((0, 1, 1, 0.5))
ax.legend(handles[4::2], labels[4::2], title="N° of people", loc="lower right", handletextpad=4, labelspacing=3, markerfirst=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Really, appreciate it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I am of the opinion that if you have to rearrange a seaborn graph substantially, you can also create this graph from scratch with matplotlib. This gives us the opportunity to have a different approach to display this categorical vs categorical plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle
import numpy as np

#dataframe and categories 
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

X = "embark_town"
Y = "class"
H = "alive"
bin_dic = {0: "yes", 1: "no"}

#counting the X-Y-H category entries
plt_df = df.groupby([X, Y, H]).size().to_frame(name="vals").reset_index()

#figure preparation with grid and scaling
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
ax.set_ylim(plt_df[Y].unique().size-0.5, -0.5)
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, plt_df[X].unique().size+1.0)
ax.grid(ls="--")

#upscale factor for scatter marker size
scale=10000/plt_df.vals.max()
#left marker for category 0
ax.scatter(plt_df[plt_df[H]==bin_dic[0]][X], 
           plt_df[plt_df[H]==bin_dic[0]][Y], 
           s=plt_df[plt_df[H]==bin_dic[0]].vals*scale, 
           c=[(0, 0, 1, 0.5)], edgecolor="black", marker=MarkerStyle("o", fillstyle="left"), 
           label=bin_dic[0])
#right marker for category 1
ax.scatter(plt_df[plt_df[H]==bin_dic[1]][X], 
           plt_df[plt_df[H]==bin_dic[1]][Y], 
           s=plt_df[plt_df[H]==bin_dic[1]].vals*scale, 
           c=[(1, 0, 0, 0.5)], edgecolor="black", marker=MarkerStyle("o", fillstyle="right"), 
           label=bin_dic[1])

#legend entries for the two categories
l = ax.legend(title="Survived the catastrophe", ncol=2, framealpha=0, loc="upper right", columnspacing=0.1,labelspacing=1.5) 
l.legendHandles[0]._sizes = l.legendHandles[1]._sizes = [800]

#legend entries representing sizes
bubbles_n=5
bubbles_min = 50*(1+plt_df.vals.min()//50)
bubbles_step = 10*((plt_df.vals.max()-bubbles_min)//(10*(bubbles_n-1)))
bubbles_x = plt_df[X].unique().size+0.5

for i, bubbles_y in enumerate(np.linspace(0.5, plt_df[Y].unique().size-1, bubbles_n)): 
    #plot each legend bubble to indicate different marker sizes
    ax.scatter(bubbles_x, 
               bubbles_y,
               s=(bubbles_min + i*bubbles_step) * scale,
               c=[(1, 0, 1, 0.6)], edgecolor="black")
    #and label it with a value
    ax.annotate(bubbles_min+i*bubbles_step, xy=(bubbles_x, bubbles_y), 
                ha="center", va="center",
                fontsize="large", fontweight="bold", color="white")

plt.show()
```

[image]